# Matching ugly extra abbreviations and numbers in titles with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I have to create regex to match ugly abbreviations and numbers. These can be one of following "formats":

```
1) [any alphabet char length of 1 char][0-9]
2) [double][whitespace][2-3 length of any alphabet char]
```

I tried to match double:

```
preg_match("/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$/", $source, $matches);
```

But I coldn't get it to select following example: **1.1 AA My test title**. What is wrong with my regex and how can I add those others to my regex too?

Comment: Please define the characteristics of "ugly abbrevations". I think with numbers regex has enough in the toolcase to offer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you say "start of string, followed by maybe a - followed by at least one digit or followed by 0 or more digits, followed by a dot and followed by at least one digit and followed by the end of string.

So you regex could match for example.. `4.5, -.1`  etc. This is exactly what you tell it to do.

You test input string does not match since there are other characters present after the number 1.1 and even if it somehow magically matched your "double" matching regex is wrong.

For a double without scientific notation you usually use this regex :

```
[-+]?\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\b
```

Now that we have this out of our way we need a whitespace \s and

```
[2-3 length of alphabet]
```

Now I have no idea what [2-3 length of alphabet] means but by combining the above you get a regex like this :

```
[-+]?\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\b\s[2-3 length of alphabet]
```

You can also place anchors ^$ if you want the string to match entirely :

```
^[-+]?\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\b\s[2-3 length of alphabet]$
```

Feel free to ask if you are stuck! :)

Comment: Thank you, I got it working with your help => preg_match("/^[-+]?\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\b\s[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/", $source, $matches);

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues with your regex:

1. You try to match the whole string (as a number) by the anchors: `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. If you don't want that, remove those.
2. The number group is non-catching. It will be checked for matches, but those won't be added to `$matches`. That's because of the `?:` internal options you set in `(?:...)`. Remove `?:` to make that group catching.
3. You place the shorter digit-pattern before the longer one. If you swap the order, the regex engine will look for it first and on success prefer it over the shorter one.

Maybe this already solves your issue:

```
preg_match("/-?(\d*\.\d+|\d+)/", $source, $matches);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4I8wjd)